# jQuery is not recognized inside .js script when it is added to MVC View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having strange problem when referencing .js scripts inside MVC View cshtml file.

I have two separated scripts that I have created in identical way. Classic .js files:

In file `saveNewMeeting.js` I have this code:

```
(function () {
    var meetingDetailsModal = document.getElementById('viewMeetingDetails');
    var btnDelete = document.getElementById('deleteMeetingBtn');
    var spanMeeting = document.getElementById("closeMeetingDetails");
    var addNewMeetingModal = document.getElementById('createNewEventModal');
    var btnSaveNewMeeting = document.getElementById('createNewMeeting');

    window.onload = function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,timelineDay,listWeek'
            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            resourceAreaWidth: '30%',
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            events: '/Meeting/GetMeetingsSummary',
            resourceColumns: [
                {
                    labelText: 'Venue',
                    field: 'name'
                }
            ], 
             //more code
})();
```

And in file `member.js` I have this:

```
(function () {
    var btnAddMember = document.getElementById('selectMembers');

    window.onload(function () {
        $("#membersGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '/Member/GetAllMembers',
            mtype: "GET",
            styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
            datatype: "json",
            colModel: [
                { label: 'ID', name: 'id', key: true, width: 60 },
                { label: 'Full Name', name: 'fullName', width: 150 },
                {
                    label: 'Select', editable: true, name: 'id',
                    edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False", defaultValue: "False" },
                    formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, width: 45
                }
            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 250,
            width: 640,
            rowList: ['ALL', 30, 50, 100, 200],
            ajaxSubgridOptions: { async: false },
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });
    });

    btnAddMember.onclick = function () {
        var checkedMembers = $('#membersGrid').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        var ids = [];
//more code...
})();
```

Then I reference this scripts in MVC view like this:

```
<script src="~/js/saveNewMeeting.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/member.js"></script>
```

I am doing this at the very end of MVC view, after all HTML code. 
All js code inside `saveNewMeeting.js` works properly. But code from `member.js` acts like it doesn't recognize jQuery or javaScript, I am getting this exception:

[image]

This looks like no jQuery or JavaScript is recognized at all. Before `window.onload` event I was trying to use `document.ready` the outcome was same.
As well when I try `$(document).ready` I get message that `$` is unrecognized and that it's not a function as well.

When I go and move code from `member.js` to `saveNewMeeting.js` all the code works properly and as expected without errors or exceptions.

Both files are created on a same place and they exists in same folder:

[image]

I am not sure why one script works and the other one have problems. Did anybody had same problem? Or maybe some experience on how to fix this?

Comment: have you included `jquery.min.js`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have included jquery.min.js inside _Layout.cshtml so I guess it should be visible in all Views... for example saveNewMeeting.js sees the referece... I guess at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet you have:

```
window.onload = function () {
```

And in the second:

```
window.onload(function () {
```

The first one is the correct one, and the second is not, as stated in developer console - `window.onload is not a function`.

Comment: Damn, such a stupid mistake. Thanks that solved the problem.

Comment: @nemo_87 Select this answer as accepted (green tick under the "downvote" option) to show the question as solved.

Answer (score -2):

Insted of using window.onload try using jQuery ready function

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: I have tried that in a first place. I get this: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function. @LazyDeveloper